# LinqToSql query execution timing

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to ask about the execution timing of a LinqToSql query.

From my understanding refer to this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/). It seems that a LinqToSql query will only execute when

1. `IQueryable`'s property is accessed
2. `IQueryable`'s function (which is not returning `IQueryable`/`IEnumeration` type) is called

However, I did an experiment like that:

```
var ents = from ent in dal.ents
           select ent;

string s1 = ents.first().Value1;   // I got 1 here
Console.ReadLine();    // When the system is waiting for my input. I change the same record manually in DB, I change Value2 of ent from 2 to 3 here. 
string s2 = ents.first().Value2    // I got 2 here.
```

Why am I still getting "2" for `s2`?

From my understanding, `ents.first().Value2` should connect to the DB again and get the new `Value2`. Why am I still getting the old value?

Comment: Are you using the same datacontext? See also [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinesh.kulkarni/2008/07/02/linq-to-sql-tips-9-understanding-datacontexts-internal-caching/)

Comment: Cannot compile the code. Please write a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think I found the working principal behind.
L2S is really working like

> LinqToSql query will only **CONNECTION TO DB AND EXECUTE** when
>
> 1. IQueryable's property being accessed
> 2. IQueryable's function (which is not returning IQueryable / IEnumeration type) being called

But in additions, after L2S fetch data from DB for each record at the first time. It will cache the record by its PK.

Eventually, on each further fetch. It will check if the record has been fetched before.

1. yes, It will use the cached version of the record instead of the DB version.
2. If no, It will use the DB version.

P.S. The lifetime of the cached records will last until the DBContext being released.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you get Value1 on this line, the call is made to the db

```
string s1 = ents.first().Value1;
```

Then it keeps the object in memory (along with Value2).  It doesn't call the database again when you try to access Value2.

Comment: Then what should I do to force it connect to DB again?

Comment: And its'n the blog said everytime we try to access the entity, it will connect to DB as long as it is not returning IQueryable object? Or I interpreted it wrong?   Thanks!